# How to redirect a specific location to that location on a different domain?

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

So I have a virtual host defined in nginx that is supposed to redirect to two different domains. Any URL using `domain-x.com` is supposed to redirect to `domain-a.com` but `domain-x.com/info` exactly is supposed to redirect to `domain-b.com/info`. I have tried this in two different ways.

Generally my entry looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-x.com www.domain-x.com;

    location ...

    return 307 $scheme://domain-a.com$request_uri;
}
```

This makes the general redirect from `domain-x.com` work somewhat. For the `location` I have tried the redirect in two ways:

```
location /info/ {
    return 307 $scheme://domain-b.com/info;
}
```

and:

```
location /info/ {
    proxy_pass http://domain-b.com/;
}
```

I also tried this with `location = /info/` to no avail.

The problem I run into is that any URL like `domain-x.com/something` is redirected to `[IP]something` (IP being the address of the server where nginx runs) and this also applies to `/info` which ends up as `[IP]info`. When I enter `[IP]/info` the redirect works  as expected. Can you help  me sort out my problems, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the naked return in the `server` block overrides any `location` blocks at the same level.

Either protect the default `return` by wrapping it inside the default `location` block, so that all of the location blocks are evaluated correctly. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-x.com www.domain-x.com;

    location / {
        return 307 $scheme://domain-a.com$request_uri;
    }
    location = /info {
        return 307 $scheme://domain-b.com/info;
    }
}
```

Or, use a `rewrite` in front of the `return` as these directives are evaluated in in order. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain-x.com www.domain-x.com;

    rewrite ^/info$ $scheme://domain-b.com/info redirect;
    return 307 $scheme://domain-a.com$request_uri;
}
```

Of course, the second example uses a 302 response rather than your desired 307 response.

In both examples I have assumed an exact match for the `/info` URI, but both are easily modified to accept `/info` as a prefix.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more details.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions and they give me the same result: `[IP]info/` this time with a slash at the end. I'm starting to wonder if there are other settings interfering although I did disable all other virtual hosts.

Comment: I would suggest you try a browser plug-in/tools to analyse the `Location` header in the HTTP response and identify exactly which server is returning an IP address rather than a domain name.

Comment: Should have used `curl` earlier... You were right in suspecting that the target server was creating the problems.